# Protect against "Overposting Forms" within Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, model-binding

Overposting a form is a common way of manipulating data / hacking a site.
The cause for that possible security problem is the Form/Model Binder, that automatically binds a Form to an object. Within ASP.NET, I know how to protect against these sort of attacks.

We have a User Model, with the following fields: ID, Firstname, Lastname, Password. I want the user to be able to change his Firstname and Lastname.
As we know, this happens within Symfony (and ASP.NET MVC) with a Form/Model Binder, that takes the "names" of the forms and maps these values to the corresponding object fields.

Solution in ASP.NET, using the [Bind] expression on each "Post-Controller":

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="FirstName,Lastname")] Employee employee)
```

How can I prevent this kind of attack within a Symfony application? How to tell the Model/Form binder, which post data should only be accepted / expected?

@Edit:
This question intended to know how to solve this kind of problem when using a FormType for multiple usecases, e.g. for Creation and Edit of an employee. I know that in general, Symfony Form Component already checks if there are any additional fields.

Comment: Quick question. Did you read the full documentation of the [Form Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html)? Also, there is [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html)

Comment: Yep already did, there stands nothing about "Protecting against Overposting" - Validation is for properties, not for my case. So as you read the Form Component documentation, you can tell me where the article about solving my problem is :)

Comment: The full documentation states everything you are asking for, and some other types of protection.

Comment: (There's some borderline non-constructive conversation going on here; please keep it civil and positive, folks! Reported to mod for deletion).

Comment: Hey, question is already answered and accepted. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['type'] === 'edit') {
            $builder->add('editMe');
            //More edit me fields
        }

        $builder->add('createMe');
        //more create me fields            
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'type'
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'type' => 'create'
        ));
    }

    //For consistency 
    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

There is no need for extra events since it would be an overkill.

Controller:

```
public function createFooAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new FooType(), new Foo());

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid() && $form->submitted()) {
        //flush form
    }

    return $this->render("AppBundle:Foo:create.html.twig", array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
}

public function editFooAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $foo = ... //find($id)

    $form = $this->createForm(new FooType(), $foo, array(
        'type' => 'edit'
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid() && $form->submitted()) {
        //flush form
    }

    return $this->render("AppBundle:Foo:edit.html.twig", array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```

[Bonus](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#handling-form-submits)

Comment: Now I understand, yes this would Work too, Was reading on mobile did not see all.

Comment: Besides the part you copied from my answer your answer is off-topic. It is useful but off-topic.
@user3746259 you should not accept answers that solve your follow-up-comment-question, you could have created a separate question for this.

Comment: Hey Marcel, I understand what you mean but this is really the best approach for my question: "How can I prevent this kind of attack within a Symfony application? How to tell the Model/Form binder, which post data should only be accepted / expected?" The intention was to use a FormType as a Service multiple times, maybe I should have pointed that one out better in my question, updating it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the cookbook (read: normal) approach to symfony forms, you already have that protection, alongside with CSRF protecttion.

If you add an extra field to the request you will get the following error:

> This form should not contain extra fields

Example Form:

```
class FooType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title');
        //Class Foo also has a text attribute
    }
}
```

You will create an edit or create form using the above class in your controller and only the fields added to the builder can be modified. This way Foo::$text can not be modified using the form.

Comment: Nice approach, but let's have the typical following situation: You have a form type, that you use for creating employees and editing employees. During the edit process, you have all the fields in the buildForm method that you also have during the creation process (Because dry = you use the same formtype for creation and edit mode). How would you handle it there ? You could easily "inject" values into the form that exist in the buildForm method -  but you don't want the user to be able to edit. You could add the creation attributes via events within the buildForm, but is this the only approach?

Comment: You cannot easily "inject" (why the need of quotes?) values to a form on submission, unless it is on pre submission and it is your code that is "injecting" the values. 

Also, you could define your own form options, to keep it DRY

Comment: @user3746259 you can remove a form element using ```$builder->remove('title');```, either in your controller or in an form event listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#event-listeners

Comment: So as an attacker, you can easily inject a new html element into the dom, which then gets posted to the server. Understand now what I mean? Thats what my approach would look like, but in Symfony Form Type you need to work with events within the buildForm method to dynamically add / remove fields.

Comment: So thanks @MarcelBurkhard I will accept your answer, because the event listener seems to be the offical answer.

Comment: @user3746259 Symfony doesn't care as much about S.O.L.I.D. as it should. 
Thanks for accepting

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard I was saying exactly what you were saying. If a form has extra field "injected" it will tell you that and will not result as valid

Comment: No what I wanted to point out is how you handle the situation when using one Form type for create and edit with different fields

Comment: As I reread the cookbook entry and looked up some other productive example pages, i come to the conclusion that using events for "initializing" the correct form is not the 100% correct way. It would work, of course - but they are designed for changing the form dynamically on other purpose (see docs. example therefore). "pre_set_data" event as for my part, is not the correct way solving this - instead replacing the pre_set_data event with passing the mode into the options array is better. that's why I accepted the other solution.